# setInterval not clearing on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have 2 problems. first is the clearInterval does not seem to be working as the image continues to rotate when the mouse cursor is over the image. second is the rightDisc is the setInterval seems to not work on the rightDisc. all the other functions do work. I tried looking into threading with web workers but that's all sorts of confusing me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/imgRotate.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function()
    {
        $("#leftDisc").rotate();
        $("#rightDisc").rotate();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img id="turnTableImage" src="turntable.jpg" height="400" width="600" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div id="leftDisc" style="margin-top: -280px; margin-left: 50px">
        left<img id="leftDiscImg" class="discs" height="200" src="disc.png" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div id="rightDisc" style="margin-top: -300px; margin-left: 350px">
        <img id="rightDiscImg" class="discs" src="disc.png" alt="" />right
    </div>
</body>
```

imgRotate.js

```
(function($) {  
$.fn.rotate = function() {
    var img = this.find(".discs");
    var imgpos = img.position();
    var x, y, xCenter, yCenter, x1, y1, deg = 1, drag = false;

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        deg++;
        $("#leftDiscImg").css("transform","rotate("+deg+"deg)");
        $("#leftDiscImg").css("-moz-transform","rotate("+deg+"deg)");
        $("#leftDiscImg").css("-webkit-transform","rotate("+deg+"deg)");
        $("#leftDiscImg").css("-o-transform","rotate("+deg+"deg)");
        $("#leftDiscImg").css("ms-transform","rotate("+deg+"deg)");
    }, 20);

    $(window).load(function() {
        img.removeAttr("width");
        img.removeAttr("height");

        xCenter = imgpos.left + (img.width() / 2);
        yCenter = imgpos.top + (img.height() / 2);
    });

    img.mousemove(function(e) {
        x1 = e.pageX;
        y1 = e.pageY;
        x = x1 - xCenter;
        y = y1 - yCenter;

        r = 360 - ((180/Math.PI) * Math.atan2(y,x));

        if (drag == true) {
            img.css("transform","rotate(-"+r+"deg)");
            img.css("-moz-transform","rotate(-"+r+"deg)");
            img.css("-webkit-transform","rotate(-"+r+"deg)");
            img.css("-o-transform","rotate(-"+r+"deg)");
            img.css("ms-transform","rotate(-"+r+"deg)");
        }
    });

    img.mouseover(function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
        deg = 1;

        if (drag == false) {
            drag = true;
        } else {
            drag = false;
        }
    });

    img.mouseout(function() {
        drag = false;

        interval = setInterval(function() {
            deg++;
            $("#leftDiscImg").css("transform","rotate("+deg+"deg)");
            $("#leftDiscImg").css("-moz-transform","rotate("+deg+"deg)");
            $("#leftDiscImg").css("-webkit-transform","rotate("+deg+"deg)");
            $("#leftDiscImg").css("-o-transform","rotate("+deg+"deg)");
            $("#leftDiscImg").css("ms-transform","rotate("+deg+"deg)");
        }, 20);
    });
}; 
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: post a demo on jsfiddle.net. Should learn to cache selectors. Using `$("#leftDiscImg")` many times means many searches of the DOM....caching in variable reduces searches

Comment: also..have you tried `mouseenter` rather than `mouseover`? And..are errors thrown in console?

Comment: @charlietfl not to mention calling `css` 5 times in a row when it could be called once.  `$discImg = $('#leftDiscImg');  $discImg.css({ 'transform': 'rotate()' /* .. */ });`

Comment: short answer is your interval variable isn't in scope when it's being cleared or the function isn't actually firing. Agree with charlietfl post fiddle, otherwise console debugging sounds in order.

Comment: k well i'm having a hell of a time trying to figure out jsfiddle. i apologize for my novice skill level. here's the link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/faytAlvein/wkjFe/4/ . although it's not working at all.

Comment: @charlietfl I tried mouseenter in place of mouseover and nothing changed. here is a link to the fiddle i attempted to make but nothing is working at all there. http://jsfiddle.net/faytAlvein/wkjFe/8/ .

Comment: @Peter the function is firing and the variable is in scope. i checked using alerts before asking the question. the variable keeps accumulating

Comment: @mmmshuddup it is my understanding that each transform is for different browsers so by using all of them then the program should be crossbrowser compatible.

Comment: and there is no errors in showing in the console. My thought is maybe the interval is getting reinitialized somewhere but if that were the case then the alert wouldn't show it accumulating.

Comment: here is fiddle comfigured to run with jQuery... I'm not sure what is expected to happen http://jsfiddle.net/wkjFe/9/

Comment: your biggest problem is that you are calling the plugin function twice...but code in the plugin is only set up to work on left side. Calling it twice sets up 2 intervals . If you comment out ` $("#rightDisc").rotate();` the left side seems to work OK

Comment: cleaned up code and made it so it works on both sides. http://jsfiddle.net/wkjFe/10/

Comment: @charlietfl it's perfect. fiddle has a slight error but the actual works perfect. i'm curious what you did to fix it. i see $ in front of the mouse functions and you combined the css calls all into one which is super sweet.

Comment: main change was to remove specific references to `$("#leftDiscImg")`  and let plugin find the correct image based on parent that was initialized. WHen you initiated plugin on left and right.... left was getting 2 intervals set on it causing problems. Changing variable name `img` to `$img` is purely semantic, is just a common way to write a variable that helps suggest that `$img` is a jQuery object

Comment: @charlietfl /facepalm lols so....the $("#leftDiscImg") was from me experimenting with setInterval. Can't believe i forgot to change that to img. I've spent well over 15 hours on this. I really appreciate the help and explanation.